# Solving while loop time complexity algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am having quite a hard time figuring out the time complexity of my algorithm. I know that the "for" portion of the algorithm will run in O(n) but I am unsure of my while loop. The problem involves creating a binary tree from a given vector. Each node is evaluated for its value and its index in the vector so, essentially, every following node must be to the right of the previous and depending on whether its value is greater or smaller, it will be a child node or a parent node. The children of the parents nodes must be smaller in value.

I have used the while loop for the case where a child node is smaller than the next node to be placed, and I follow up through the parents until I find the spot for the new node to be placed. I beleive this will run, in the worst case, k-1 times, k being the depth of the tree, but how would I represent this as a time complexity? O(kn)? Is that linear?

```
for(int i = 0; i < vecteur_source.size(); i++){
    if( i == 0){
        do bla....
    }else if((vecteur_source.at(i) > vecteur_source.at(i-1)) && (m_map_index_noeud.at(i-1)->parent)){
        int v = m_map_index_noeud.at(i-1)->parent->index;
        while ((vecteur_source.at(i) >= vecteur_source.at(v))){
            v = m_map_index_noeud.at(v)->parent->index;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to simplify this into pseudocode:

```py
# I'm assuming this takes constant or linear time
do the thing for i = 0

for i ← 1 to n-1:
    if source[i] > source[i-1] and nodes[i] is not the root node:
        v ← nodes[i-1].parent.index
        while source[i] > source[v]:
            v ← nodes[v].parent.index
```

If I've understood it properly from your code, then your analysis is correct: the outer loop iterates O(*n*) times, the inner loop iterates up to O(*h*) times where *h* is the height of the tree, so therefore the time complexity is O(*nh*).

This is not linear time, unless *h* is guaranteed to be at most a constant. More usually, *h* is O(log *n*) for balanced trees, or O(*n*) in the worst case for unbalanced trees.